# Why is referencing sheet by index still implicity referencing referencing by activesheet

Tags: excel, vba, rubberduck

I Have the below code which formats a sheet. There are multiple sheets in this workbook so i only want to take actions on the first one. However if i have any sheet other than the first activated such as the second the code throws a 1004 error. I am not sure why as i am specifying and defining the target worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectByJobNumber()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim OperatingRow As Variant
    Dim CountOfMatching As Long
    
    Dim WB As Worksheet
    Set WB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    
    LastRow = WB.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    
        WB.Range(Cells(LastRow + 2, 19), Cells(LastRow + 2, 22)).Formula = "=" & "Sum(S74:S" & LastRow & ")"
        WB.Range(Cells(LastRow + 2, 19), Cells(LastRow + 2, 22)).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
    
    For OperatingRow = 74 To LastRow
        
        If WB.Cells(OperatingRow, 3) = WB.Cells(OperatingRow + 1, 3) Then

            CountOfMatching = CountOfMatching + 1

        Else
            
                WB.Range(Cells(OperatingRow - CountOfMatching, 3), Cells(OperatingRow, 21)).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlMedium
                WB.Cells(OperatingRow - CountOfMatching, 22) = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(OperatingRow - CountOfMatching, 21), Cells(OperatingRow, 21)))
                
                If WB.Cells(OperatingRow - CountOfMatching, 22) = 0 Then
                    WB.Cells(OperatingRow - CountOfMatching, 23) = "Text for Zero Total Payable"
                Else
                    WB.Cells(OperatingRow - CountOfMatching, 23) = "Not Paid"
                End If
                
                WB.Cells(OperatingRow - CountOfMatching, 22).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"

            CountOfMatching = 0
            
        End If
        
    Next OperatingRow
    
    If WB.Cells(LastRow + 2, 21) = WB.Cells(LastRow + 2, 22) Then
        WB.Range(Cells(LastRow + 2, 21), Cells(LastRow + 2, 22)).BorderAround ColorIndex:=4, Weight:=xlMedium
    Else
        WB.Range(Cells(LastRow + 2, 21), Cells(LastRow + 2, 22)).BorderAround ColorIndex:=3, Weight:=xlMedium
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use `WB.Cells`. BTW `ws` is kind of more appropriate for worksheets, while `wb` is used for workbooks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that in code like this:

```
 WB.Range(Cells(LastRow + 2, 19), Cells(LastRow + 2, 22))
```

The object `Cells` isn't qualified and so it's defaulting to `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells()`. It feels silly though because you already qualified the `Range()` which takes `Cells()` as arguments, but those arguments are their own object and must also be qualified.

Consider instead:

```
With WB
   .Range(.Cells(LastRow + 2, 19), .Cells(LastRow + 2, 22))
End With
```

Or you can just qualify them each individually with `WB.` if that feels cleaner.